# Open folder on click of button; depending on what field is selected

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on a database. This database involves projects; you can click a button to add a project, and when you do that it shows you all the projects in a datasheet subform on another page.

How would I be able to link a folder to a certain project? So when you are entering all the information into fields, you can also enter a folder location and when you save it, it saves it to the table. Now once you go to the subform, click that field, and click the "Open Folder" button it opens the folder on your computer. Though also note, these folders would be on a server; external from the computer's main hard drive.

Form names are: DatabaseF & AddProjectF

Subform name is: ProjectQSubF

Table name is ProjectsF.

Network location is G:\

Thanks!

Sorry I didn't put this in at first, wasn't thinking. I know how to open a folder location of a preset in the code with a button; I just don't know how to attach that code to change depending on what field you are clicked on.

This is the code I use currently to open up folders preset in the code it self:

```
Private Sub ProjectFolderBtn_Click()
    Dim x As Variant
    Const msgTitle As String = "Open Explorer"
    Const cExplorerPath As String = "C:\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE"
    Const cExplorerSwitches As String = " /n,/e"
    Const cFilePath As String = "G:\Projects\Walmart"

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    If Dir(cExplorerPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Explorer Path '" & cExplorerPath & "' could not be found.", vbCritical, msgTitle
        x = Shell(cExplorerPath, vbNormalFocus)
    ElseIf Dir(cFilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Path '" & cFilePath & "' could not be found.", vbCritical, msgTitle
        x = Shell(cExplorerPath, vbNormalFocus)
    Else
        x = Shell(cExplorerPath & cExplorerSwitches & "," & cFilePath, vbNormalFocus)
    End If

    Exit Sub
    Error_Handler:

    MsgBox "An error has occurred trying to open Explorer", vbCritical, msgTitle

    End Sub
```

To decide what field you are currently selected, you have to pull the ProjectID from another form which will still be open in the background named DatabaseF. There is a hidden textbox on there that is called txtProjID; that's what I did for my More Info button that I have (which is where the open folder button will be located). That is all I know on how to do it though, I don't know the actual code that goes together to fetch the selected field and open the directory from the stored information in the table.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet? Or are you asking for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Edited my main post, sorry I forgot to add my knowledge and what to do, and a better description of what I am looking for help on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to edit this to align with your variable and field names, but what needs to be edited **should** be obvious.

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from ProjectsF WHERE ProjectID = " & Me.ProjectID & "")

cFilePath = rec("FilePath")
```

Put this somewhere at the top, take out the hard-coded cFilePath const and you should have a dynamically set file path.

Comment: I'm not sure why my question got -2, though really all that matters is you helped me fix my problem and it is working now! Thanks, much love.